# How can i add my slideshow images into default slideshow?

Tags: theming, nodes

I cannot change my slideshow images into default slideshow in my corporateclean theme. I am using drupal 7. Anybody help me how can i add my content in that theme. I am new to drupal.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1227474) there is no interface for changing the slides. You should do it in code.

In the [page.tpl.php file](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/corporateclean/tree/page.tpl.php?h=7.x-1.x), you'll find multiple pieces of code like this:

```
<!--slider-item-->
    <div class="slider-item">
        <div class="content container_12">
            <div class="grid_12">

            <!--slider-item content-->
            <div style="float:left; padding:0 30px 0 0;">
            <img class="masked" src="<?php print base_path() . drupal_get_path('theme', 'corporateclean') ;?>/mockup/slide-1.jpg"/>
            </div>
            <h2>Sample product name</h2>
            <strong>General</strong><br/>
            <em>Client name</em><br/>
            <br/>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
            <div style="display:block; padding:30px 0 10px 0;"><a class="more" href="#">Tell me more</a></div>
            <!--EOF:slider-item content-->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--EOF:slider-item-->
```

Those are your slides and that is where you can edit them. But if you are not tech savvy, you could also choose to disable the default slider (appearance > corporate clean settings > disable slideshow) and implement another slide show module like [views slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow).

By using another module you can use 'normal' content for the slides and position the slideshow as a block. There are plenty of tutorials and youtube videos. If you run into trouble you are free to ask here for help again.